# jQuery chained selects

Tags: jquery

i'm using http://www.appelsiini.net/2010/jquery-chained-selects for a project.
You can find the source here https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_chained

this file in particular https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_chained/blob/master/jquery.chained.js

Child select options must have class names which match option values of parent select.

Option values may (most likely will) have characters (e.g. spaces or &) that are invalid for class names.

Like for instance:

```
<select id="mark">
  <option value="">--</option>
  <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<select id="series">
  <option value="">--</option>
  <option value="series 3" class="bmw">3 series</option>
  <option value="series 5" class="bmw">5 series</option>
  <option value="series 6" class="bmw">6 series</option>
  <option value="a 3" class="audi">A 3</option>
  <option value="a 4" class="audi">A 4</option>
  <option value="a 5" class="audi">A 5</option>
</select>
```

and that will not work!

Any thoughts on a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use underscore for classes and values: long_name_here

Comment: i set the values on the fly. not possible in this case :(

Comment: jQuery('.ms-RadioText > option').each(function () {
            jQuery(this).addClass(jQuery(this).val());
        });

Comment: how can i append _ to a 3 and any values that have spaces in it?

Comment: you can use var vl= jQuery(this).val(); vl = vl.replace(/ /g,”_”) ;jQuery(this).addClass(vl);

Answer (score 2):

Since values are "behind the scene", never seen by users, why don't you remove or escape special characters from them ?

For instance:

```
<option value="a_3" class="audi">A 3</option>
```

Comment: i set the values on the fly. not possible in this case :(